# How can I get the value from a parent html page into a javascript popup page?

Tags: javascript

I have a php page where a date value is POSTed back to. From this php script, I want to forward that value to a javascript window. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The opened window should have access to the parent window through `window.opener` from there you can access your parent document.

Try something like this in your popup window:

```
alert(window.opener.document.getElementById('mydate').innerHTML);
```